# Can't get feature file to run through Jenkins

Tags: ruby, jenkins, cucumber, rubymine

I'm trying to get our automation environment set up to run headless through Jenkins on a linux server. The automation is set up through Ruby and uses Cucumber. I've run into an issue trying to get the feature files to run.

I have several plug ins for Jenkins, Xfvb, Cucumber reports, Cucumber-plugin.

I have setup the code in Ruby set up correctly (at least I believe so) for one of the feature files to run as headless.

But I can't quite get to test that specific file. When I try to run the build after enable the Cucumber-plugin it tries to run a different feature file. It seems to want to run the entire project. I've tried to add a new profile in my cucumber.yml (name jenkins) file and specify a tag like below:

```
jenkins: --tags @DisposalFeeService --no-source --format pretty --format html --out results.html --format json --out reports.json
```

I only have 1 feature file that is tagged with that tag and my build runs a completely different feature file. The feature is failing for good reasons, nothing to do with the Jenkins set-up, it would fail anyways. I also haven't set up all the features to run as headless, nor do I want to at this time. I'm just trying to show that I can get a feature file to run in through Jenkins.

If it is helpful, here is my cucumber-plug in in Jenkins: [Cucumber Jenkins plug in](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v8l3M.png)

Comment: It looks like if I just run cucumber featurefile in the shell it will try to run that feature but no step definitions. So it doesn't actually run. How do I get Jenkins to run the feature and recognize the step definitions but not run the entire project?

Comment: Are you able to run headless locally on your machine ? If that works, try to execute the same command on Jenkins, directly using build-> execute shell, rather than the plugin. Should help you identify where the problem is.